# ajax call raises unexpected login dialog in a web application project

Tags: asp.net, ajax, authentication, web-config

I am having trouble with Windows Authentication after converting a Web Site Project to a Web Application Project. I started with creating a new Web Application Project with WinForms and Windows Authentication. Then, besides of deleting unneeded default content and copying over my own content, I noticed that the login dialog appeared where I did not expect this.

To temporarily cure this, I simply disabled authentication by changing:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
```

to:

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
```

in web.config. Similar: `<allow users="?"\>` to `<allow users="*"/>`
I can now access all aspx pages, but still getting the login dialog on an ajax call from an aspx page.

With Fiddler I found that the ajax call looks ok:

```
    POST http://localhost:60578/...bla_bla.aspx/GetSampleDescription HTTP/1.1
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Referer: http://localhost:60578/...bla_bla
    Accept-Language: nl-NL
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
    Host: localhost:60578
    Content-Length: 15
    DNT: 1
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=vieai......yy1txo

    {"Barcode":"4"}
```

however, the response is 401 Unauthorized.

Then, the IE browser repeats the request with an additional Authorization header, which fails, etc etc.

The question is: why does the above ajax call gets a 401 Unauthorized response, while the aspx page gets 200 OK? What setting in web.config could fix this? Are there other factors in play here?

Comment: An aspx's methods typically aren't exposes as endpoints to the outside world. You should move your `GetSampleDescription` method to an asmx or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An aspx's methods typically aren't exposed as endpoints to the outside world. You should move your `GetSampleDescription` method to an asmx or something like that.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed my problem. No idea why my earlier ajax web services worked in aspx files just fine, but the asmx file is definitely simpler.